# ElasticSearch - Search if this term include in the list index or not?

Tags: elasticsearch

It was mapped like this:

```
                            "parent_ids": {
                                "type": "text",
                                "fields": {
                                    "keyword": {
                                        "type": "keyword",
                                        "ignore_above": 256
                                    }
                                }
                            }
```

The actual data looks like this:

```
parent_ids = ["asdf", "aeraeg", "A123"]
```

I want to filter all products with `parent_ids` "A123":

```
"filter":
                    {
                        "match": {
                            "parent_ids": "{{parent_ids}}"   
                        }
                    }
```

But not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You can use [terms query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) that returns documents that contain one
> or more exact terms in a provided field.

**Search Query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "terms": {
      "parent_ids.keyword": [ "A123"]
    }
  }
}
```

**Search Result:**

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "64745756",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "parent_ids": [
            "asdf",
            "aeraeg",
            "A123"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Search Query using bool query:**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "match": {
          "parent_ids": "A123"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to format your query to support a [JSON array](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-template.html#search-template-converting-to-json) in parameters, you'll need to format your query like this:

```
{
    "terms": {
        "parent_ids.keyword": {{#toJson}}parent_ids{{/toJson}}
    }
}
```

Note that the `match` query doesn't support an array of values, only the `terms` query does.